# JS <select> element with conditional visibility/functionality

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, google-chrome

I am currently working on a form, where users can change some settings. I include a setting to change the role of a user (user, admin, superadmin), which is only supposed to be enabled for users with the 'superadmin' role.

Image of how it looks like now

[image]

After a superadmin changes a role, I want the value to be saved when i click the save button that I have at the bottom of my form.

So far I have tried to change the properties of the `<select>` element to Enabled for 'superAdmins', where i made the default value 'disabled' and vice versa.

Any ideas on how I could fix the function? thank you!

```js
var userRole = "superAdmin"; // user.getDataByKey('role');
//change user role

function editUserRole() {
  var changeUserSelect = document.getElementById("sub-user-role");

  if (userRole === 'superadmin') {
    changeUserSelect.disabled = false;
    //$("#sub-user-role").prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    //$("#sub-user-role").prop('disabled', true);
    changeUserSelect.disabled = true;

  }
}
```

```html
<label for="sub-user-role" class="translate_text" data-translation="USER_ROLE"></label>
<select id="sub-user-role" name="userRoleInfo" class="userRoleInfo" type="text">
  <option value="user" class="optionUser" data-translation="USER_ROLE_USER">user</option>
  <option value="admin" class="optionAdmin" data-translation="USER_ROLE_ADMIN">admin</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update to include any relevant HTML like your button

Comment: First of all, string comparation is case-sensetive, so try `userRole === 'superAdmin'`

Comment: hey @mplungjan  thanks for the quick reply! i added an image of what it currenlty looks like. I want the selector to be grayed out or disabled if the user does not meet the requirements of superadmin

Comment: Anything else is fine and should work, maybe mistake outside of provided snippet. When/where you called `editUserRole`?

Comment: I am not sure what your goal is because `user` in your code refers to the user of the app that manages other users if I am not mistaken? I would call them differently to clarify the use case, for example `appUser` and `databaseUser`.

Comment: also can you specify what you mean with "I want the value to be saved when i click the save button". Where do you want to save the new user role value? Because once you select the new user role, the dropdown will display that new value. If you claridy I will try to help.

Comment: I have a database setup with all the apps users, inlcuding staff also refered to as "superAdmins" in the code. only the staff/superAdmins are supposed to be able to change the role of any given user with the selector in the form. is this understandable? @thomas

Comment: There might be a problem outside of the snippet, but its hard to tell since im getting no errors and there are close to 300,000 lines of code in the project. I just placed trhe function in the global scope, and have not called it specifically @Xeelley

Comment: @thomas user data is sent to the backend via POST

{"username": 'Be4Energy_Test'

"email": "email@email.com",

"role": "admin",

"b4v_permissions": {...}}

Im assuming the value (string: user, admin, superAdmin) in the form is supposed to be updated.

Comment: Try to call it immediately `(function editUserRole() { ... })()`, anything changed?

Comment: I think that seemed to work! I ended up also switching the 2 commented out lines for the ones underneath. Thanks @Xeelley !!

Comment: You are welcome! :)